# Recover data from a select and send it to the database

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I just started laravel recently and I have a problem.

I have a 'select' in a 'form' and I would like to retrieve the selected data and save it in the database.

Unfortunately, I have the impression that the data is not selected

here is the select :

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3 ">
        <select class="custom-select @error ('category') is-invalid @enderror" id="category">
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value={{ $category->id}}>{{ $category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('category')
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {{$errors->first('category')}}
            </div>
        @enderror
    <div class="input-group-append">
```

here is the Controller :

```
$request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|min:5',
        'content' => 'required|min:10',
        'image' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp',
        'category' => 'required'
    ]);

    $topic = new Topic();

    $topic->title = $request->input('title');
    $topic->content = $request->input('content');

    $id = DB::table('categories')->where('name', $request->input('category'))->value('id'); //get the category id
    $topic->categorie_id = $id;
```

here is the error :

[bugSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaayE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a name="category" to your `<select>`, if not it's not sent by the form.

```
<select name="category" class="custom-select @error ('category') is-invalid @enderror" id="category">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <option value={{ $category->id}}>{{ $category->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```